# The average number of events with exponential interarrival time until the time between two events exceeds a certain value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Well, the question itself is self-explanatory. 
There's an exponential distribution for the time between every two events with an average of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. 
Is it possible to know the average number of events that happen until the interarrival time between two events which has the mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is greater than a constant like $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the interarrival times are exponential random variables with rate $\lambda$, the probability for any given one of them to exceed $T$ is $e^{-\lambda T}$, and they are independent.  So the number of arrivals $N$ needed for this to happen is a [geometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p = e^{-\lambda T}$.  Its mean is thus $1/p = e^{\lambda T}$.

Comment: I can't argue with that. Thank you.